# Screen messes up when opening browser

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, screen

Somebody I know is having a problem with their computer (Ubuntu 16.04). They can log in just fine. When they open an internet browser (they have google chrome and firefox, and they've tried both) the entire screen glitches out. It shows sort of a striped pattern on the screen. What is causing this and how can it be fixed?

UPDATE: Now it is also doing it when system settings is opened.

Comment: Check your `dmesg` output. Notice red lines log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put how I solved this whenever I first figured it out, but I'm answering this anyway to help anyone else who might have this problem. The person was using a very old graphics card and it was not fully supported by the Nouveau driver. I set it to use the Nvidia legacy binary driver (304.135) and it worked.